# I need to calculate the arctan(x) and the result is showing "nan", what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++

So the value that im getting is "nan" and i suspect something is wrong in my while statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   int n=1,c=0;
    float x;
    double sum=0, old_sum, diff=1000000,eps;
    cin>>x>>eps;
    while(abs(diff)>=eps){
        old_sum=sum;
        sum=sum+double(pow(x,n)/n)*double(pow(-1,c));
        c++;
        n+=2;
        diff=sum-old_sum;
}
    cout<<sum<<"\n";
    cout<<atan(x);
    return 0;
}
```

My input is 21 for x and 0.01 for eps and what i get is nan and the correct value done by the atan function.

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: What if `n` overflows? You should add a check.

Comment: `sum=sum+double(pow(x,n)/n)*double(pow(-1,c));` could be simplified to just `sum += (pow(x,n)/n) * pow(-1,c);`

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/4nTaaqW5G, it seems to work well.

Comment: Just in case of wrong input, remember that your series is only valid for |x| < 1

Comment: How should i check for n overflowing?
On godbolt for every other value other than 1 i get a nan.
How should i correct the |x| < 1 problem?

Comment: @Rocco nope, the Taylor series converges for |x| < 1, but atan(x) is defined for any x.

Comment: Yes, sorry I confused the Taylor series with the function ;-)

Comment: But why is atan(21) still giving a valid answer then?

Comment: Oh didnt see that :))))

Comment: You should check for  |x| < 1. Hint: arctan(x) = arccotan(1/x)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.
```#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, n, m, ctr, x;
    double sum, old_sum, mm, nn;
    double diff = 1000000000;
    double eps = 0.001;

    cout<<"x= ";cin>>x;
    cout<<"eps= ";cin>>eps;
    cout<<endl;
    i = 1;
    sum = x;
    m = -1;
    while (abs(diff) >= eps) {
        old_sum = sum;
        ctr = (2 * i + 1);
        mm = double(pow(x, ctr))/double(ctr);
        nn = mm * m;
        sum = sum + nn;
        m = m * (-1);
        i++;
        diff = sum - old_sum;
    }

Comment: This is what my friend did but they feel the same, like i cant identify where i am wrong

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add missing information there, comments are not suitable for such updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- You don't take into account that the formula is only valid for `abs(x) <= 1`. This can be solved by a little mathematical trick
- You don't check that the formula converges effectively. This can be done with a test of the value of `n`
- You are repetidly using the `pow(.)` function. This is useless. This doesn't provide bad results, but it is quite inefficient

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int n_max = 200;
    double x;
    double eps;
    std::cin >> x >> eps;
    double x_sav = x;
    x = x / (1.0 + sqrt(1+x*x));        // the trick to handle abs(x) > 1
    int sign = -1;
    double term = x;
    double powerx = x;
    double sum = x;
    double x2 = x*x;
    while (std::abs(term) > eps && n <= n_max) {
        powerx *= x2;
        term = powerx / n;
        sum += term * sign;
        n += 2;
        sign = -sign;
    }
    if (n > n_max) {
        std::cout << "The series did not converge\n";
        return 1;
    }
    sum *= 2.0;     // following of the trick
    std::cout << sum << "\n";
    std::cout << atan(x_sav) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however I have some questions, and I'm sorry in advance for asking, but what is the trick called and how does it work? I haven't seen something like this done and I am curious about this one in particular.

Comment: I just use the formula `atan(x) = 2 atan(x/(1+sqrt(1+x^2)))`. I simply found this formula on wikipedia [Inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).